# How to Merge multiple arrays into a matrix in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

Is there an easy way to merge multiple, say char arrays to get a char matrix? I have 8 arrays below with 64 chars each and I want to merge to a matrix with 8 rows and 64 cols.

```
package august26;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class XBits {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    long n1 = input.nextInt();
    long n2 = input.nextInt();
    long n3 = input.nextInt();
    long n4 = input.nextInt();
    long n5 = input.nextInt();
    long n6 = input.nextInt();
    long n7 = input.nextInt();
    long n8 = input.nextInt();

    String s1 = String.format("%64s", Long.toBinaryString(n1)).replace(' ', '0');
    String s2 = String.format("%64s", Long.toBinaryString(n2)).replace(' ', '0');
    String s3 = String.format("%64s", Long.toBinaryString(n3)).replace(' ', '0');
    String s4 = String.format("%64s", Long.toBinaryString(n4)).replace(' ', '0');
    String s5 = String.format("%64s", Long.toBinaryString(n5)).replace(' ', '0');
    String s6 = String.format("%64s", Long.toBinaryString(n6)).replace(' ', '0');
    String s7 = String.format("%64s", Long.toBinaryString(n7)).replace(' ', '0');
    String s8 = String.format("%64s", Long.toBinaryString(n8)).replace(' ', '0');

    s1.toCharArray();
    s2.toCharArray();
    s3.toCharArray();
    s4.toCharArray();
    s5.toCharArray();
    s6.toCharArray();
    s7.toLowerCase();
    s8.toCharArray();
    input.close();
}
```

}

Comment: There are some problems with your code.  `toCharArray()` returns an array, and you're not storing that returned array anywhere, making those method calls an expensive no-op.  In addition, you should be using arrays to store the results of your `input.nextInt()` calls and your formatted strings, not individual variables.  That would allow you to use `for` loops and avoid all that repetitive code.

Comment: You may want to look into multi-dimensional arrays

Comment: isn't this what [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) do?

Comment: Fairly certain a matrix in this regard would simply be a two dimensional array, eg String[][]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char[][] matrix = new char[8][];
matrix[0] = s1.toCharArray();
matrix[1] = s2.toCharArray();
```

etc...

Comment: That's only a tiny part of the OP's problems.

Comment: Oh, well since this answer is accepted, I guess I can stop typing my answer now.

Comment: I agree @RobertHarvey, there is much to be fixed in this code.  Include for loops, change the format string to get rid of replace(), for starters.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No way - contribute another answer.  If it's better, it might get a lot of up-votes.  I'm sure you can do better than I since I don't specialize in Java.

Answer (score 0):

untested pseudocode:

```
package august26;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class XBits {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Character[]> charArray = new ArrayList<Char[]>(); 
    while (input.hasNextInt()) {
        charArray.add(
            String
                .format("%64s", Long.toBinaryString(input.nextInt())
                .replace(' ', '0')
                .toCharArray()
        );
    }
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: You meant `ArrayList<Character[]>` or `ArrayList<char[]>`, right?

Comment: As I said, it's untested, so probably.  I'm not exclusively a Java dev, so I might miss some of the finer details.